# Convert string to bigdecimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp with javascript function.Within that I have BigDecimal return value.I want to put that to var variable by converting String to BigDecimal in javascript.Is there any way to convert that?

My code is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var amount=bigdecimalvalue;
 </script>
```

I get the big decimal value from a list using ajax.I want only to convert the bigdecimal value to String.

Comment: yes why not possible try parseFloat() of javascript

Comment: please provide (max value) that is in your variable

Comment: oye mem sorry but i cant hear that the double is datatype in javascript.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First you want convert it into String using toString() method.Then stored it into double variable usind Double.parseDouble() method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var amount=bigdecimalvalue.toString();
double amountindouble=Double.parseDouble(amount);
</script>
```

Comment: double is not a valid data type in javascript. I couldn't understand why this was made as owner's accepted answer.

Comment: downvoted as this is not a valid answer. running this will throw an error that will sum it:"Double is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var amount=bigdecimalvalue.toString();
 </script>
```